# MySQL using multiple indexes on order by

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, mariadb

I have a system that is using order by to return data to a user interface; the user may select from a dozen different sort options in any order.

I have the query

```
explain extended select t.* from task t order by create_date, due_date limit 5;

+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------+----------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | filtered | Extra          |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------+----------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | t     | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 331233 |   100.00 | Using filesort |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------+----------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

I have an index on create_date as well as due_date. I know I could create an multi-column index; however, as there are about 12 different sort options, that means I would have to create over a hundred indexes to cover all scenarios.

I read about index-merging and I believe that would solve the problem as I could create a index for each column you can sort by however I can't seem to get it to work on the "order by" part of the query.

Comment: Do you have an actual question?

Answer (score 1):

DBMS are fairly good at sorting even when there isn't an index.  Remember that extra indexes slow down update operations, so there certainly can be such a thing as 'too many indexes' on a table.

There's no guarantee that the data can be presented using an index if the query is complex, or that using the index is the fastest query plan.

For example, you might have a very good filter condition on ColumnA (which selects just 1/1000 of the million rows in the table) while you want to sort on ColumnB and ColumnC.  In that case, the optimizer is likely to perform better using the index on ColumnA and sorting the 1000 result rows rather than reading the whole 1,000,000 row table in the order of the index on ColumnB and ColumnC and selecting the 1 in a 1000 rows that satisfy the filter condition.

Usually, the optimizer knows better than you do.  Not always; there are even occasionally bugs and sometimes oversights in the implementation.  But as a first rule of thumb, unless you can rewrite the query to get the same result radically faster, the optimizer is likely to be doing a decent job.
(If you can rewrite the query and get the results faster, then the optimizer has blown it, and you've got a good basis for a bug report.)

Answer (score 0):

only way you can do is force the index

force index index_name for order by

if you want to take the advantage of index merge
then try using union, or , etc which will make you to use multi indexes

remember always that a multi indexing will be used at the time when both the condition which are independent to each other then only it will work

in rare cases it is possible to make use of multi indexes

( here for the above query i am sure it won't work )

Answer (score 0):

Try this workaround:

```
explain extended select * from (select t.* from task t order by create_date limit 30) z order by create_date, due_date limit 5;
```

It can work when you have all your rows within top 30  rows, while using the first order.

The "Trick" is select a simle query from the main table, and do the larger things (joins, advanced orders, random, etc) on a 30-rows set, that faster than use a whole 330K rows table.